# How do I use tensorboard with pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensorboard

I was following the pytorch tensorboard tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html.

But I can't even start because of the following error:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~/apps/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/__init__.py in <module>
      1 try:
----> 2     from tensorboard.summary.writer.record_writer import RecordWriter  # noqa F401
      3 except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorboard'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c8ffdef1cfab> in <module>
----> 1 from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
      2 
      3 # default `log_dir` is "runs" - we'll be more specific here
      4 writer = SummaryWriter('runs/fashion_mnist_experiment_1')

~/apps/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/__init__.py in <module>
      2     from tensorboard.summary.writer.record_writer import RecordWriter  # noqa F401
      3 except ImportError:
----> 4     raise ImportError('TensorBoard logging requires TensorBoard with Python summary writer installed. '
      5                       'This should be available in 1.14 or above.')
      6 from .writer import FileWriter, SummaryWriter  # noqa F401

ImportError: TensorBoard logging requires TensorBoard with Python summary writer installed. This should be available in 1.14 or above.
```

I installed pytorch 1.14 via conda. Am I supposed to install something else?

Comment: They should probably let you know that you need to install tensorboard in that tutorial. Take a look at the [pytorch tensorboard docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html) which explains that you need to install tensorboard first.

Comment: @jodag Thanks. I see. So how should I install it?

Comment: I generally use `pip install tensorboard` but there may be a conda method as well.

Comment: Thanks @jodag. If you post a small answer with those comments I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That tutorial should probably let you know that you need to install tensorboard. Take a look at the [pytorch tensorboard docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html) which explains that you need to install tensorboard first.

Basically you can install tensorboard using

```
pip install tensorboard
```

and then start the tensorboard server by running

```
tensorboard --logdir=runs
```

The `runs` directory is where your summary writer will write to and it's where the tensorboard server reads from to know what to visualize.